# Most efficient way to process mysql query, only "on submit"?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i set up a php form to insert data into my db, and noticed the query would run by default every time the page was refreshed.  figured i could just move the query into it's own file, and then call it "on submit"...but that didn't work.  what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your form is being POSTed to the server, then

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... process the form
}
?>
```

Checking for the presence of an input field is unreliable - you might change the field's name and forget to update the fieldname check. This method is 100% - the REQUEST_METHOD value will always match how the script was invoked.

Comment: alternative method is: if ($_POST) { ... }

Comment: @hafichuk: $_POST is present (as an empty array) regardless of request method - all the superglobals are ALWAYS present.

Comment: @Mark correct, however in the context of an if statement an empty array evals to false

Comment: Still not reliable - the form could consist of checkboxes, none of which are selected, leading to an empty _POST.

Comment: You are correct, however that is a fairly rare edge case in my experience.

Comment: Yep, but using a 100% reliable method is preferable to one that has edge cases.

Comment: i fkn love this site lol.  thx guys!  the request method worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you do it save this file as connection.php Please be aware there is no validate script here. This is just a simple example of how to insert the record into database using php mysql on a same page.

```
Save this file as conn.php
<?php
$hostname_tfc_conn = "servername";
$database_tfc_conn = "connname";
$username_tfc_conn = "dbusernanme";
$password_tfc_conn = "dbpassword";
$tfc_conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_tfc_conn, $username_tfc_conn, $password_tfc_conn)     or     trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
Now name the following page as you want

<?php
include_once("conn.php");
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                  ($_POST['name'], "text"),
                  ($_POST['password'], "text"),
                  ($_POST['email'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_tfc_conn, $tfc_conn);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $tfc_conn) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "filename.php";//Put you filename here if the record is successful
header("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <p>Name : 
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
 </p>
<p>Email: 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</p>
<p>Password: 
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

Comment: what's the use of sprintf in the header? why not to make it just `header("Location: $insertGoTo");`?

Comment: it's not actually "bad" but i see no use for the sprintf here. it just makes the code 2 times longer with no benefit.

Comment: instead of that long and and still erroneous code to get current url for the action you can either use REQUEST_URI or - even better - just leave action blank.

Comment: @NoPHPknowldege .1 your code is the autogenerated code by DreamWeaver. What's that GetSQLValueString function? I know its generated by DW, but are you sure is what OP needs? Did he say he has DW and he's using that code? I don't think this is gonna work for him. Besides, it's unnecessary complicated

Comment: ok first thing first is it not PHP code? if yes Does it does what OP needs? Yes. So whats the problem doesn't matter as a developer you would have use ZF so what is it illegal@DamienPirsy

Comment: I'm not saying this is illegal, but you should mention "This code is from DW, it uses a DW database function wich you need to have in order for this to work". IF I provide a Zend library with code, I would say that, otherwise you're not helping much,especially if OP doens't use Zend and you didn't explain what your code does. I know this is PHP code, but that isn't enough to make it the _right_ code for the job! Start by telling what OP could do with the GetSQLValueString() function, and where it is defined. If from your code OP needs to strip the part he needs, why not doing that yourself?